# Join query issue - syntax error near join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

```
   TRADERS                                            INCENTIVE
   __________________________________________      _____________
   TRDID  NAME  SUPERVISOR  LOCATION   PAY         TRDID  INCENTIVE
   ------------------------------------------      -------------
  66  Chad                 NY         110000        17    5000
  17  Yena          66     TN          75000        21    2000
   5  Karam         66     TN          80000         66    5000
  21  Rose           5     HI         100000      ...


 --group by highest pay for location and traderid                                               

                   select e.trdid trdid, e.location, max (e.pay+ coalesce(b.incentive, 0))  maxtotal  from traders e
                        join incentive b on e.trdid = b.trdid
                            group by e.location, trdid
                   join (                       
                   (select e.trdid trdid, max (e.pay+ coalesce(b.incentive, 0))  maxtotal  from traders e
                join incentive b on e.trdid = b.trdid
               group by e.location, e.trdid)) using (trdid)
```

I get an error when I try to join the table and its subquery.
I am trying this in PostgreSQL

I am trying to get only the  highest paid trader in each location based on ranking of pay and incentive put together as totalpay.  I want to print
   trader name, pay, incentive, and total pay (pay plus incentive).

Please can you advice what is wrong with my query? I get an error stating syntax error near join

Comment: I am not an expert in postgresql, but i would say you miss the from clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your query, sort-of formatted:

```
select e.trdid trdid, e.location, max (e.pay+ coalesce(b.incentive, 0))  maxtotal
from traders e join incentive
     b
     on e.trdid = b.trdid
group by e.location, trdid join
     ((select e.trdid trdid, max (e.pay+ coalesce(b.incentive, 0)) as maxtotal
       from traders e join
            incentive b
            on e.trdid = b.trdid
       group by e.location, e.trdid
     ))
     using (trdid)
```

You seem to misunderstand SQL syntax.  `JOIN` is an operator only understood in the `FROM` clause.  `GROUP BY` is a separate clause.  It goes *after* the `FROM` clause.  I suppose you intend:

```
select e.trdid trdid, e.location, max(e.pay + coalesce(b.incentive, 0))  maxtotal
from traders e join
     incentive b
     on e.trdid = b.trdid join
     (select e.trdid trdid, max(e.pay+ coalesce(b.incentive, 0)) as maxtotal
      from traders e join
           incentive b
           on e.trdid = b.trdid
      group by e.location, e.trdid
     ) b
     using (trdid)
group by e.location, trdid;
```

You may notice that I format my queries so the SQL clauses are aligned on the left.  This is why `FROM` and `GROUP BY` are on the left, but `JOIN` is not.

But, I think a much easier way to write the query is:

```
select distinct on (e.trdid) e.trdid as trdid, e.location,
       max(e.pay + coalesce(b.incentive, 0)) as maxtotal
from traders e join
     incentive b
     on e.trdid = b.trdid
group by e.trdid, e.location
order by e.trdid, maxtotal desc
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot really do:

```
select .... from ....
 join ... on ....
group by ....
 join ....
```

If you want to join two aggregate subqueries, use common table expressions (`with` clauses). Better is to try to do your set operations and then aggregate at the end.